# ¿Cómo puedo sumar las columnas de una matriz y la suma guardarla en un arreglo?

Tags: java

como puedo sumar las columnas de una matriz y esa suma guardala en un arreglo
se hacer la suma de las columnas  pero no se como guardarlas. la matriz es 12*4 donde 12 equivale a la filas y 4 a las columnas alguna idea como hacerlo ? gracias

```
int sumas[] = new int[4];
 public void sumar(int matriz[][]) {
        int suma;
      
        for (int i = 0; i < fila; i++) {
            suma = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                // 1. sumar todos los elementos
                suma += matriz[i][j];
                // guardar en un arreglo
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[][] matriz = new int[12][4];

int[] resultado = new int[4];


// iterar las columnas
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // recorrer las filas
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        // sumar todas las filas de esa columna
        // y guardarlo en el arreglo
        resultado[i] += matriz[j][i];
    }
}
```